# Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "memechannel" is not found error (discord.py)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, bots, discord.py

Alright, so I have made a Discord Bot that takes memes from reddit and sends it to a user specified channel every 5 minutes, to do this i had to make a `cog`

```py
#imports
import discord
...
...
#Automemer
class Automemer(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, client):
....

#used to loop the task of posting memes
    @tasks.loop(minutes=5.0)
    async def automemer(self):
        all_subs = []
...
#start of formating embed for task loop
            name = random_sub.title
            url = random_sub.url
            em = discord.Embed(title = name)
            em.set_image(url = url)
            em.color = 0xff0000
em.set_footer(text=f'Memes from r/AmongUsMemes')
            #used to post the memes where the user does the command am.memechannel
            @commands.command()
            async def memechannel(self, ctx):
                channel_id = ctx.channel.id
                await ctx.send('Memes will now be sent in this channel')
                memeChannel = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
                if memeChannel:
                    emoji1 = ':arrow_up:'
                    emoji2 = ':arrow_down:'
                    msg = await ctx.send(embed=em)
                    await msg.add_reaction(emoji1)
                    await msg.add_reaction(emoji2)
                    await ctx.send(embed=em)
```

`Error = Ignoring exception in command None: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "memechannel" is not found`

The error happens whenever I run the command am.memechannel.

It would be great if somebody told me how to fix this error.
This is the last feature of the bot, and it will be my first ever Discord Bot released to the public! :)

Answer (score 1):

You defined the commands inside of the task loop, your indentation is messed up. You're supposed to put the command *underneath* the loop, not inside of it.

```
@tasks.loop(minutes=5.0)
...

@commands.command()
...
```

Keep in mind that your `em` variable is only visible within your task so you'll have to find a way to work around that, otherwise you can't use it in your command. An example is adding it as a class variable instead.

```
def __init__(self, client):
    self.em = discord.Embed()
```

And then just overwriting that variable as you go along.

```
self.em = discord.Embed(title=name)
...
```